# Deploy using artifact from artifactory

Tags: deployment, artifactory, bamboo

Is there a way in Bamboo to deploy artifacts from artifactory rather than only local published artifacts? I've found the [Artifactory Plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bamboo%20Artifactory%20Plug-in) but as far as I could see, it only allows for deploying stuff into artifactory.

I'm using Bamboo 5.4.2

Comment: You mean deploy to something like Application Server?

Answer (score 2):

You can use your build server to deploy from Artifactory to your application server, that's a very detoured way to go. You already uploaded all the binaries to Artifactory why would you want to download them to the build server again?

You have number of ways to get the needed files to your application server right from Artifactory, without involving the CI server, and the selection depends on how complicated your requirements are. If all you need is to get the latest version of some artifact from Artifactory to app server, tools like [LiveRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/liverebel/) are a great match. If you need to do more, e.g. deploy on sophisticated topology of clustered environment with sharded data schema upgrade without downtime, you might need something more free-style like [Puppet, Chef, Ansible, or Salt](http://www.infoworld.com/d/data-center/review-puppet-vs-chef-vs-ansible-vs-salt-231308).

In any way, [Artifactory Properties](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Properties) and the [REST API](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API) to work with them are your best friend. Using properties in your REST queries for artifacts allows expressing queries like "Give me all the artifacts that were produced by certain Bamboo build, but only those, which were staged, have the QA level of 'production' and matching the target deployment target".

Comment: Bamboo is not only a build server but also has special deployment-plans for exactly that purpose. I can't imagine that there's no way for Bamboo to be able to use artifacts from Artifactory for deployment without building a custom script to use the REST-API from Artifactory.

Comment: Jenkins can also manage that. CIs can be involved in deployments.

Comment: @will, Vince (and all the other downvoters), I added explanation why going directly from Artifactory to application server is preferred than going CI Server -> Artifactory -> CI Server (again) -> application server.

Comment: LiveRebel was discontinued in 2014.

Comment: @sim this answer is from 2014.